# TimeSpan: The specified type member 'TotalHours' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this code

```
var late_list = context.Results
                    .Where(r => ((TimeSpan)r.time_late).TotalHours > 0)
                    .ToList();
```

It doesn't like the `TotalHours` thing. the error is : "The specified type member 'TotalHours' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

So, how can I query using a timespan? ('time' type in SQL).

Answer (score 1):

I just used a new timespan to compare with.

```
TimeSpan zero_time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
var late_list = context.Results.Where(r => ((TimeSpan)r.time_late) > zero_time).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

I had a where clause where I had to ignore the Time in a DateTime where clause.

```
.Where(t => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.LogTimeStamp) >= fromDate)
.Where(t => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.LogTimeStamp) <= toDate)
```

For your case please check the [DbFunctions.DiffHours Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffhours%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and consider to use EntityFramework 6. And it may not directly help you as you are working with the TotalHours.